# JakartaEE vs Spring vs Java SE com JPA

Tags: java, java-ee, spring-jpa, ejb, persistência

Fala devs, beleza?

Lendo a documentação da Oracle encontrei o seguinte trecho:

@PersistenceContext protected EntityManager entityManager;

Daí o EJB container vai injetar uma persistence unit padrão aí. Isso também funciona com Spring. Mas eu tenho dúvidas sobre JPA sem ser Spring ou EJB. Já fiz vários demos usando persistence.xml, mas o que isso significa? Ao usar JPA eu necessariamente estou usando JEE? JPA é do JEE, pois não? Posso usar partes do JEE dentro do JSE, no caso? Sabem onde eu vejo uma introdução conceitual sobre esse assunto?

Answer (score 1):

JEE abrange várias coisas. Uma delas é a especificação (não implementação) JPA, que foi feita inspirada no framework de ORM Hibernate, e posteriormente o Hibernate se adaptou a ela e implementou essa especificação (mas também manteve particularidades que não seguem a JPA, não sei se na mesma versão).

Persistência não envolve só ORM, pode ser feita até em arquivos-textos, então não sei se eles tratam só de ORM ou não. Mas certamente a parte de ORM tem um grande peso na especificação.

Você pode adotar uma implementação de JPA (que pode ser Hibernate ou outra) na sua aplicação JSE para fazer a persistência de dados. Não acho que dê para dizer que virou uma aplicação JEE porque a JEE são várias coisas e uma delas que me parece central são os EJBs e as propriedades que eles têm rodando em um *container*, e que não estarão sendo utilizados no caso, mas sua aplicação estará adotando uma especificação que faz parte da JEE, no caso o modelo de persistência.

(Posso estar falando besteira, você disse que o *EJB container* injeta a *persistence unit* (que deve ser portanto um EJB), né? Então já não entendo mais nada rs. Mesmo assim acho que eu classificaria como JEE a sua aplicação se ela usasse outros recursos JEE que não só a persistência. Ou pelo menos se usasse JPA/Hibernate para também estar usando EJBs e não só o Hibernate. Ah sei lá...).

Introdução a isso acho que seriam coisas como ler a especificação da JEE, a da JPA, e a página do Hibernate. Wikipedia em inglês também pode ajudar. E também ler sobre a diferença entre JPA e Hibernate; a versão não-JPA deste último pode dispor de otimizações para certos bancos ou para o tratamento de dados em geral que a JPA por tentar ser mais generalista não oferece.

P.S.: De Spring eu não sei nada, quem quiser complementar fique à vontade. E posso ter falado alguma coisa desatualizada.

Comment: "que deve ser portanto um EJB" sim. O Spring também fornece um contêiner e também consegue injetar a unidade de persistência. Contudo, quando uso JPA com JSE, eu preciso instanciar a PU com EntityManagerFactory, usamos aquele famoso JpaUtils com o emf como singleton criado num bloco static. Mas lembrei que aplicativo web com tomcat também não é JEE, é só uma parte do JEE, então já entendi o que eu queria...

Comment: Tomcat tem aquela história de implementar só o tal do Web Profile, que se eu não me engano foi criado justamente para fazer esse tipo de diferenciação (em oposição a um "full profile" do JEE acredito eu).